# R code to iterate over lists, combining them into a data frame with grouping variables?

Tags: r, list, iteration, grouping

I am tasked with collecting table names, grouping variables, variable names, and variable values from a large number of complex XML Esri Workspace files. At the most basic level, I am having trouble iterating over lists I am able to generate that contain grouping variables in a way that repeats for grouped variable names and values.

So, for a list of table names `(table 1, table 2)` and lists of variable names `(A, B)` and values `(1, 2)`, I am hoping to pull together a data frame that looks like this:

```
TABLE    NAME   VALUE
table 1  A      1 
table 1  B      2
table 2  A      1
table 2  B      2
```

The method needs to be flexible enough to accommodate several layers of groups of differing lengths across files.

In its simplest form, for a list of two table names and two variable names:

Here is my best try using a for loop to do this. Instead it loops over each list separately rather than duplicating the table name grouping each variable name:

```
tableNames <- c(seq(1:2))  
varNames <- c("A", "B")  

results <- cbind(rep(0, length(tableNames) + length(varNames)), 0)  
for(i in seq_along(tableNames)){  
    results3[i, 1] <- tableNames[i]   
  for(j in seq_along(varNames)){  
    results3[i, 2] <- varNames[j]  
  }  
}  
results
```

> ....[,1] [,2]
> [1,] "1"  "B"
> [2,] "2"  "B"
> [3,] "0"  "0"
> [4,] "0"  "0"

I was hoping for results to look like this:

> ....[,1] [,2]
> [1,] "1"  "A"
> [2,] "1"  "B"
> [3,] "2"  "A"
> [4,] "2"  "B"

Comment: Does this work for you? `expand.grid(tableNames, varNames)`

Comment: I think you get this result with ```expand.grid(tableNames, varNames)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `crossing` from `tidyr` package:

```
tableNames <- c(seq(1:2))  
varNames <- c("A", "B")  

crossing(tableNames, varNames)
```

```
tableNames varNames
       <int> <chr>   
1          1 A       
2          1 B       
3          2 A       
4          2 B
```

Comment: Both of these work for my 2x2 example. The tidyr function crossing() is nice because it retains list names as column names. I will try adding each of these to my larger XML code to see if one or both are flexible enough to deal with multiple grouping layers and differing list lengths across files.